# SSRS Conditional Formatting Doubles Numbers and Displays Wrong Percentage

Tags: reporting-services, formatting

All:

I have two columns in my SSRS Report.  They are:  Data (float) and Format (varchar).

Format can have one of three values:  "N", "%", "$".

If the format column is "N", I need to format the column as "#,##0".  If the column is "%", I need to format the column as a percent.  If the format is "$", I need to format it as currency.

However, nothing I do is working.

I have tried:

```
=Switch(Fields!month_4_tformat.Value="N", Format(Fields!month_4_Data.Value,"#,##0"), Fields!month_4_tformat.Value="%", Format(Fields!month_4_Data.Value,"P"), True, Format(Fields!month_4_Data.Value,"C"))

=iif(Fields!month_4_tformat.Value="N", Format(Fields!month_4_Data.Value,"#,##0"), iif(Fields!month_4_tformat.Value="%", Format(Fields!month_4_Data.Value,"P"),  Format(Fields!month_4_Data.Value,"C")))
```

Both of these will cause unexpected results.  If you look at the screen shot, column 2, last cell is "228722870", although the database value is only 22870, so the value is being shown twice, but column 1, 3, 4 and 5 are valid.  Row two, column 1 is wrong, as the value in the database is "0.2", so the percentage should be "20%".  Column three shows "1616.00" percent, but it should be "16%" as the value in the database is "0.16".  None of the numbers are formatted as "#,##0".

What am I donig wrong?  Any help is appreciated.....

[image]

Comment: Format is controlled by the actual textbox properties. You might want to adjust those instead.

Comment: Alternatively make sure all of your textboxes are formatted to string and then convert all of your numbers to string with CSTR(). That should display correct.

Comment: Do you have any other formulas outside of your formatting ones?  The format seems to be working so curious if it is actually something else prior to the format.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help.  the CSTR function solved my problems.  Would never have thought about this and appreciate the help from you guys.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the CSTR function is what was needed or at least solved the issue for me